# How do I create a tuple with the "Tuple" class out of input provided from the user

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace c_sharp_exercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide 6 numbers seperated by space:");
            var line = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");
            var num1 = int.Parse(line[0]);
            var num2 = int.Parse(line[1]);
            var num3 = int.Parse(line[2]); 
            var num4 = int.Parse(line[3]); 
            var num5 = int.Parse(line[4]); 
            var num6 = int.Parse(line[5]); 
            var num7 = (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6);
            Console.WriteLine(num7);
        }
    }
}
```

Which will ask for 6 different numbers and when providing numbers let's say from 1-6, then it will print the following in the terminal:
`(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`.
My question is how do I do this with the `Tuple` class?

What I tried is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace c_sharp_exercises
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide 6 numbers seperated by space:");
            var line = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ");
            var num1 = int.Parse(line[0]);
            var num2 = int.Parse(line[1]);
            var num3 = int.Parse(line[2]); 
            var num4 = int.Parse(line[3]); 
            var num5 = int.Parse(line[4]); 
            var num6 = int.Parse(line[5]); 
            Tuple<int,int,int,int,int,int> tuple = line;
            Console.WriteLine(tuple);
        }
    }
}
```

Which gave me the following error:
`error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'System.Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int>'`

What am I doing wrong here and should I change my whole approach?

Comment: `var tuple = new Tuple(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6);`

Comment: `Please provide 6 numbers seperated by space` ... `Console.ReadLine().Split(",")`.  You're setting yourself up for an exception there.

Comment: Indeed - you're asking the user to enter numbers separated by spaces but you're *actually* splitting them by commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a string (or an array) into a Tuple.
Instead you can do

```
var tuple = Tuple.Create(num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6);
```

Answer (score 0):

see this link [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)

> You can define tuples with an arbitrary large number of elements:

> var t =
> (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
> 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
> 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26);
>
> Console.WriteLine(t.Item26);

The `num7` that you defined is actually a tuple:

```
     var num7 = (num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6);
```

if you run this code, you see the result:

```
string _type = num7.GetType().Name;
Console.WriteLine(_type); //the result is ValueTuple`6
```

Comment: I'm guessing OP is doing an old exercise where the new `ValueTuple` was not part of the language yet and it therefor asks for `Tuple`.